# Problem with toString() method in the LinkedList implementation. Java

Tags: java, linked-list, nullpointerexception, tostring

I just tried to implement a linked list and when I only added two elements, it threw `NullPointerException` in the `toString` method in the debugger, but I can't get why. It's OK while it's empty, it prints [], but then it throws an error. Maybe you could help me to figure out what's wrong with my `toString()` method?

The desirable output is [A, B, C] or [] if a list is empty.

My whole code:

```
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.NoSuchElementException;

public class ListImpl implements List {
    private Node head;
    private Node tail;

    private static class Node {
        Object data;
        Node next;

        Node(Object d) {
            data = d;
            next = null;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void clear() {
        if (size() > 0) {
            head = null;
            tail = null;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public int size() {
        int size = 0;
        Node currentNode = head;
        while (currentNode != null) {
            size++;
            currentNode = currentNode.next;
        }
        return size;
    }

    public Iterator<Object> iterator() {
        return new IteratorImpl();
    }

    private class IteratorImpl implements Iterator<Object> {

        @Override
        public boolean hasNext() {
            return head != null;
        }

        @Override
        public Object next() {
            if(hasNext()){
                Object data = head.data;
                head = head.next;
                return data;
            }
            return null;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void addFirst(Object element) {
        Node newNode = new Node(element);
        newNode.next = null;
        if (head == null) {
            head = newNode;
        }
        else {
            newNode.next = head;
            head = newNode;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void addLast(Object element) {
        Node newNode = new Node(element);
        newNode.next = null;
        if (tail == null) {
            tail = newNode;
        }
        else {
            newNode.next = tail;
            tail = newNode;
        }
        
    }

    @Override
    public void removeFirst() {
        if (head == null) {
            System.err.print("The first element is absent");
        }
        head = head.next;
    }

    @Override
    public void removeLast() {
        if (head == null)
            System.err.print("Your list is empty");

        if (head.next == null) {
            System.err.print("There is only one element");
        }

        // Find the second last node
        Node second_last = head;
        while (second_last.next.next != null)
            second_last = second_last.next;

        // Change next of second last
        second_last.next = null;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getFirst() {
        if(head!=null) {
            return head.data;}
        else
            throw new java.util.NoSuchElementException("List is empty");
    }

    @Override
    public Object getLast() {
        if(head == null){
            throw new java.util.NoSuchElementException("List is empty");
        }
            Node last = head;
        while (last.next != null)
        {
            last = last.next;
        }
        return last;
    }

    @Override
    public Object search(Object element) {
        Object result = null;
        while (head.next != null)
        {
            if (head.data.equals(element)){
               result = head.data;
            }
        }
        return result;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean remove(Object element) {
        boolean isFound = false;
        if(head == null) {
            throw new NoSuchElementException("List is empty!");
        }
        if(head.data.equals(element)) {
            head = head.next;
            return true;
        }

        Node currentNode = head;
        Node previousNode = null;
        while(currentNode !=null) {
            if(currentNode.data.equals(element)) {
                isFound = true;
                break;
            }
            previousNode = currentNode;
            currentNode = currentNode.next;
        }
        if(currentNode == null) {
            return isFound;
        }
        currentNode = previousNode.next;
        previousNode.next = currentNode.next;
        currentNode.next = null;
        return isFound;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        Node current = head;
        if(head == null) {
            return "[]";
        }
       StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
        result.append("[");
        while(current.next != null) {
            result.append(current.data + ", ");
            current = current.next;
        }
        result.append(tail.data + "]");
        return result.toString();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
    ListImpl list = new ListImpl();
    list.addFirst("FirstElement");
    list.addFirst("SecondElement");
        System.out.println(list);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in the line

```
result.append(tail.data + "]");
```

You don't update the tail in the method `addFirst()` and in other methods too, if you correct that, it should work.

Feel free to add comments to my answer for clarifications.

Comment: I just chaned it to 

`@Override
    public void addFirst(Object element) {
        Node newNode = new Node(element);
        newNode.next = null;
        if (head == null) {
            head = newNode;
            tail = head;
        } else if (head == tail) {
            head = newNode;
            tail = head.next;
        }
        else {
            newNode.next = head;
            head = newNode;
        }
    }`


But it still throws an exception :(

Comment: You should draw your list on a piece of paper... Your changes are still not correct, in the "if" and "else if" body is missing the newNode.next set